# Inherited class options--overwriting values

Tags: document-classes

I've built a custom class based on `scrbook`. I have some default options for the inherited `scrbook` (eg. 9pt), but I would like to pass valid `scrbook` options via `myclass` to overwrite those defaults (eg. 15pt) I set. It seems that the options I pass to `myclass` come before the options passed to `scrbook`, but I would like them to come after.

```
\documentclass[15pt]{myclass}  % I want the 15 pt to overwrite the default 9pt

\begin{document}
 Hello
\end{document}
```

myclass.cls

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{myclass}

\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{scrbook}}

\ProcessOptions\relax

\RequirePackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
      texio.write_nl('>>>>>>>'..token.get_macro('@classoptionslist'))
\end{luacode*}

\LoadClass[%% Document Class
      9pt,  % 9 overwrites the 15 pt passed
    %   15pt, % if 15 pt comes after 15 pt, it wins. I want what the user specifies in main.tex to be put after the options (eg. 9pt) set here.
      % .... etc
]{scrbook}

\begin{luacode*}
      texio.write_nl('>>>>>>>'..token.get_macro('@classoptionslist'))
\end{luacode*}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\PassOptionsToClass` for the default values too:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{myclass}
\PassOptionsToClass{fontsize=9pt}{scrbook}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{scrbook}}

\ProcessOptions\relax

\typeout{>>>>> \csname opt@scrbook.cls\endcsname}

\LoadClass{scrbook}
```

This will show in the log

```
Document Class: myclass 
>>>>> fontsize=9pt,fontsize=15pt
```

Note that I use the `fontsize=XX` syntax to avoid that KOMA falls back to compability mode with lots of warnings, and that I used a simply `\typeout`. Passing through lua to show the content of a simply command seems a bit overdoing.

Comment: Easy--thanks. I didn't realize that PassOptionsToClass was additive in that way. Thanks for showing me typeout as well... I just default to lua because that my "comfort zone" and would I would have used if I needed to do so some text manipulation.